# Swift Dynamically created UILabel to use network data string as Text property

Tags: swift

Just started to lean swift.

The WKWebView loads website immediately, does not need to wait.

The below code almost working, but it is really not works well.

Because the UILable needs a long time to loads data from network, the data is a very sample string text and the network speed is very good.

Is there a graceful way to do that?

Thanks!

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
////Create a UILable labTitle dynamically////
var labTitle = UILabel()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    labTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 30, y: 30, width: 200, height: 20))
    view.addSubView(labTitle)

         ////fetching the data from url////
         URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (NSURL(string: "www.abc.org/interface/") as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
                 if error != nil || data == nil {
                     print("Client error!")
                     return
                 }
                 do {
                     let js = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])

                     ////give the string value to labTitle Text property////
                     self.labTitle.text = ((js as AnyObject)["REMOTE_ADDR"] as? String)!

                 } catch {
                     print("JSON error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                 }
        }).resume()

}
```

}

Comment: What's the problem with the code?

Comment: Code works, but it's just not works well, @Sh_Khan help me to fixed it, the problem is thread management, I am going to understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `DispatchQueue.main.async` as session callback is in a background thread

```
 let js = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any] 
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.labTitle.text = js["REMOTE_ADDR"] as? String 
 }
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! Is there a website or book to recommend to learn SWIFT Programming?